# Documentation of IOS Printer List Menu Icons

Tags: ios, icons

When the IOS printer selection menu appears, there sometimes displays icons next to the printer name.  Is there a list / documentation on these icons and what their index value is?

I have seen a cloud icon and a light icon from AirPrint helper apps on Macs / PCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are called Emojis....Emojii.... Emoji....